# Remove duplicate rows by counts in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Some of the articles did help on the stack, however, could not find to delete rows by counts in Hive.

There are 2 row_counts for Apple. How do I select only 1 row count for Apple?

--What data looks like...Total 14 records

```
customerID     date product_type            
1234abc       20140105  Orange      
1234abc       20140105  Apple       
1234abc       20140205  Orange      
1234abc       20140205  Apple       
1234abc       20140205  Apple       
1234abc       20140305  Orange      
1234abc       20140305  Apple       
1234abc       20140305  Apple       
1234abc       20140405  Orange      
1234abc       20140405  Apple       
1234abc       20140405  Apple       
1234abc       20140505  Orange      
1234abc       20140505  Apple       
1234abc       20140505  Apple
```

--Final Output. Total 10 records

```
customerID     date product_type    
1234abc       20140105  Orange      
1234abc       20140105  Apple       
1234abc       20140205  Orange      
1234abc       20140205  Apple       
1234abc       20140305  Orange      
1234abc       20140305  Apple       
1234abc       20140405  Orange      
1234abc       20140405  Apple       
1234abc       20140505  Orange      
1234abc       20140505  Apple
```

Comment: Both of your tables have 10 rows.  I don't understand what you mean by 14 records.  What does the data *really* look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Data looks like this. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Do you actually want to delete the data from your Hive table? Or do you just not want the duplicates to show in the query?

Comment: So you want to delete from your table all values of count(product_type) where product_type is apple of which has a count greater than 1?

Answer (score 1):

select distinct customerID,date,product_type from your_table

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a 2 steps approach.  step 1: create a temp table with the duplicate record list inserted, using insert and select like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp( product_Name Char( 30 ), Date Date, CustomerID int );
INSERT INTO #temp (product_Name, Date, CustomerID)
select x.dup, x.[Product_name] as nameX
      , x.[Date]  as dateX, x.CustomerID
from (
SELECT count(*) as dup
      ,[Product_Name]
      , CustonmerID
      ,[TestDate]
  FROM dbo.[yourtable]
  group by  [Date] ,[Product_Name], CustomerID ) x
  where dup > 1
```

Then delete the duplicates with

```
 delete  from 
 dbo.[originaltable] 
 where EXISTS (SELECT product_Name, Date, CustomerID from #Temp WHERE Product_Name= [dbo].[originaltable].Product_Name and Date=[dbo].[originalTable].Date )
```

step 2: Insert the #temp table contents, which has the unique row into the original table.